# How to disable label from Highchart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, highcharts

[image]

I want to disable label means that when I load a graph disable all label except first. so How can I do this?

Please help me.

Thanks, In Advance

Comment: Labels don't have a disable property. What exactly you want to do?

Comment: I want to default enable only 1 and when we click on label then it's enable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure all but the first series to have `visible: false`:

```
$('#container').highcharts({                       
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }, {
        data: [144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2],
        visible: false
    }]
});
```

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LApt3/1/).